# What is the correct terminology for an HTML/XML tag that closes itself?

Tags: html, xml, tags, xhtml

I can't remember the term that is used to describe the difference between an html tag that is self-closing,

For example, `<hr />` closes itself.

`<p>This doesn't</p>`

Comment: A self-closing tag? You just said it :)

Comment: Are you asking about (a) the difference between HTML elements that don't require an end tag and those that do (a question about the HTML spec), or (b) the syntactic difference between start tags that include the self-closing `/` and those that don't? Since you said HTML/XML, I guess it's the latter.

Comment: These are normally called void tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The term used by the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) is:

> **Empty-element tag**

The [relevant part](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags) of the specification says:

> *Tags for Empty Elements*
>
> ```
> [44]  EmptyElemTag ::= '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '/>' [WFC: Unique Att Spec]
> ```
>
> Empty-element tags may be used for any element which has no content, whether or not it is declared using the keyword EMPTY. For interoperability, the empty-element tag SHOULD be used, and SHOULD only be used, for elements which are declared EMPTY.

However, you might also frequently hear the term *self-closing tag*.

Comment: Not sure how I've never heard that before, but thanks for enlightening me!

Answer (score 2):

I have always used the term "self-closing tag". I didn't know there was another term!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know "self-closing tags".

Answer (score 1):

I've heard them referred to as void elements.

Comment: Don't confuse tags with elements. Elements are objects in the DOM that result from the mark-up being parsed. Tags are the strings of characters in the mark-up bounded by `<` and `>`. A self-closing (or empty-element) tag in mark-up, when parsed as XML, will cause an element to be added to the DOM with no content. A "void element" is an element defined such that elements of that name should *never* have content.

Comment: I'm not confusing anything. hr is a void element. All void elements are empty elements and the example the poster used was hr. There's a distinction between empty elements vs empty element tags, if that's what you're trying to point out.

Comment: That's the important distinction, yes. The question was about tags, your answer is about elements. The rest of my comment is pedantry about what is meant - in HTML - by the term "void element". For example, the markup `<svg />` will, with an HTML5 parser, create an empty element in the DOM. That doesn't make `svg` a "void element".